# Some daze about the Pascal output

Tags: linux, pascal

Platform: Linux 2.6.18 x86_64

Compiler: Free Pascal Compiler version 2.2.2 [2008/11/05] for x86_64

The source code is:

```
Program main;
var invalue:string;
Begin
        (*Until the EOF, this loop continue to work*)
        while not eof do
        begin
                Write('Please input the express: ');
                Flush(StdOut);
                Readln(invalue);
                Writeln('The expression is: ',invalue);
        end;
        Writeln('');
        Writeln('Exit the program. Bye!');
End.
```

I compiled it and run it. But the ouput is something like:

```
123
Please input the express: The expression is: 123
234
Please input the express: The expression is: 234
345
Please input the express: The expression is: 345

Exit the program. Bye!
```

The numbers are my input. I googled it, and thought it is because of the buffer. So I tried to add the flush(stdout) or flush(output) after the Write. But it still does not work well.

I hope it works as:

```
Please input the express: 123
The expression is: 123
Please input the express: 234
The expression is: 234
Please input the express: 345
The expression is: 345

Exit the program. Bye!
```

Thank you! And sorry for my fool~

---

Addition:
I tried as (Thank you, Aloush!)

```
Program main;
var invalue:string;
Begin
        (*Until the EOF, this loop continue to work*)
        while not eof do
        begin
                Write('Please input the express: ');
                Flush(StdOut);
                Readln(invalue);
                Writeln('')
                Writeln('The expression is: ',invalue);
        end;
        Writeln('');
        Writeln('Exit the program. Bye!');
End.
```

The result is still not well as:

```
1
Please input the express: 
The expression is: 1
2
Please input the express: 
The expression is: 2
3
Please input the express: 
The expression is: 3
4
Please input the express: 
The expression is: 4
5
Please input the express: 
The expression is: 5

Exit the program. Bye!
```

The Readln is still executed before the first Write.

By the way, I also tries:

```
Program main;
var invalue:string;
Begin
        (*Until the EOF, this loop continue to work
        while not eof do
        begin*)
        Repeat
                Write('Please input the express: ');
                Flush(StdOut);
                Readln(invalue);
                Writeln('The expression is: ',invalue);
        Until eof;
        Writeln('');
        Writeln('Exit the program. Bye!');
End.
```

In this case, the first loop is good, but the others are still wrong.

```
Please input the express: 123
The expression is: 123
234
Please input the express: The expression is: 234
345
Please input the express: The expression is: 345

Exit the program. Bye!
```

Thank you!

---

Final Solution:
http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/pascal/lang_ref/ref_io.doc.html#592
It's because, the eof actually corresponds to an implicit read.
The current code should be:

```
Program main;
var invalue:string;
Begin
        (*Until the EOF, this loop continue to work*)
        Write('Please input the express: ');
        while not Eof  do
        begin
                Readln(invalue);
                Writeln('The expression is: ',invalue);
                Write('Please input the express: ');
        end;
        Writeln('');
        Writeln('Exit the program. Bye!');
End.
```

Lastly, thank you, Aloush here and keiy on CSDN!

Comment: Please tick the arrow to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted". This is better than editing the title to "solved".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
Program main;
var invalue:string;
Begin
        (*Until the EOF, this loop continue to work*)
        while not eof do
        begin
                Write('Please input the express: ');
                Flush(StdOut);
                Readln(invalue);
                Writeln('')
                Writeln('The expression is: ',invalue);
        end;
        Writeln('');
        Writeln('Exit the program. Bye!');
End.
```